# I am trying to retrieve Timecard data from the Square API but the endpoint always disconnects without a response

Tags: square-connect

My account has "account_capabilities": ["EMPLOYEE_MANAGEMENT","TIMECARD_MANAGEMENT"]

I have been able to use the given python sample (with modifications for Python 3) to get sales data from the API.

I am using Python 3. Here is the code fragment:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import http.client, urllib.parse, json

# All requests to the Connect API require an access token
# in an Authorization header. Specify yours here.
access_token = '...'

# In addition to an Authorization header, requests to the Connect API should
# include the indicated Accept and Content-Type headers.
request_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                   'Accept':        'application/json',
                   'Content-Type':  'application/json'}

# Send the request to the List Payments endpoint and obtain the response.
connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection('connect.squareup.com')
request_path = 'v1/me/timecards'
connection.request('GET', request_path, '', request_headers)
response = connection.getresponse()

# Convert the returned JSON body into an array of payments you can work with.
payments = json.loads(response.read().decode(encoding='UTF-8'))

# Pretty-print the payments array.
print(json.dumps(payments, indent=2, separators=(',',': ')))
```

---

Result:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Thys>cd \Fernleaf

C:\Fernleaf>python fragment.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fragment.py", line 18, in <module>
    response = connection.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Thys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1174, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Thys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 282, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Thys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 251, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

C:\Fernleaf>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried later the endpoint was no longer timing out and I received a permissions error. It seems you need to request authorization from Square to use the employee api. Don't know why they were timing out but they are now responding with an error.